# Use Open Query with quoted items

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server, openquery

I am trying to use openquery to access a linked server. However, it appears to be impossible because, you cannot have the correct number of Single quotes. I need to pass a variable Start and End date, so I cannot use the basic openquery method, but instead must use the EXEC(@OPENQUERY+ @SQL) method. The problem is, to pass the date through the @SQL variable I must use ''' so it has 1 quote, but then when it gets passed to the EXEC(OPENQUERY+@SQL) the open query which introduces another level of quotes, causes the dates to now be not be quoted and I get an error. If I add another layer of quotes it then causes them to be double quotes causing that error. Is it not possible to use quotes in an open query? I have the same issue even passing things like Where Username = 'Jack'. I can never have the correct number of quotes.

```
DECLARE @STARTDT NVARCHAR(10) = '2019-01-01'
        ,@ENDDT NVARCHAR(10) = '2019-03-01'

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @OPENQUERY nvarchar(4000)
        , @LinkedServer nvarchar(4000)

SET @LinkedServer = 'ProductionSvr'

SET @SQL =
'select  *
from SalesData a
where a.Sale_date between ''' + @StartDt + ''' and ''' + @ENDDT + ''')
'''

print @SQL

SET @OPENQUERY = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY('+ @LinkedServer + ','''

EXEC (@OPENQUERY+@SQL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within a quoted string, you have to escape a single quote with an additional single quote, which is where you start to see the four and five single quotes in a row. In order to help simplify things, I would make a couple of suggestions.

First, keep your strings more segregated in their duties. Your `@SQL` variable includes the necessary ending punctuation for your `OPENQUERY`, but the beginning punctuation is in the `@OPENQUERY` variable. (This might be clearer in the code below.)

Also, I'd recommend using proper data types (such as your dates), and then use the `CONCAT` function, which conveniently handles all of the data type conversions for you.

So, the modified version of what you started with would look like this:

```
DECLARE @OPENQUERY nvarchar(4000)
      , @LinkedServer nvarchar(256)
      , @SQL NVARCHAR(4000);

--Set your dates. Use the right data type to avoid sending 
--invalid dates into your query. Easier to debug them here.
DECLARE @STARTDT DATE = '2019-01-01'
        ,@ENDDT DATE = '2019-03-01';

--Set your server.
SET @LinkedServer = 'ProductionSvr';

--Then set up the inner query.
SET @SQL =
CONCAT(
'select  *
from SalesData a
where a.Sale_date between ''', @StartDt, ''' and ''', @ENDDT,'''');

--Set up the OPENQUERY variable with all of the punctuation that it needs,
--so you just need to drop in your LinkedServer name and your SQL statment.
--Use CONCAT because it handles the data type conversions for you.
SET @OPENQUERY = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(',@LinkedServer,',''(',@SQL,')'')');

PRINT @OPENQUERY;
```

Result:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(ProductionSvr,'(select  *
from SalesData a
where a.Sale_date between '2019-01-01' and '2019-03-01')')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
DECLARE @STARTDT NVARCHAR(10) = '2019-01-01'
        ,@ENDDT NVARCHAR(10) = '2019-03-01'

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @OPENQUERY nvarchar(4000)
        , @LinkedServer nvarchar(4000)

SET @LinkedServer = 'ProductionSvr'

SET @SQL =
'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(' + @LinkedServer + ',''select  *
from SalesData a
where a.Sale_date between ''' + @StartDt + ''' and ''' + @ENDDT + ''')'

print @SQL
```

All you have to remember is **within quotes, double single quotes means 1 single quote**. So, ''')' essentially translates to "')". Hope this helps.

Comment: I just figured it out, the trick was 4 quotes around constants and 5 quotes around variables. If you update your answer I will make it as correct :)

Comment: I didn't quite get what you are trying to say, but I am good if you got the answer you are looking for. You may want to give the query I have put in the answer a try as well, as I believe it's a simpler version and should give the correct result.